# Pizza fries getting burnt

Tags: pizza, burnt

I am trying pizza fries. As shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rGwEEN9IHY) video. Pizza sticks are getting burnt from outer side while baking. What should I do to prevent them?

**Ingredients**

I am using Pizza break, Pizza sauce , Cheese (mozzarella).

**Recipe**

What i am doing is i am taking pizza base and on that pouring pizza sauce, then i am cutting it into pieces.

After cutting them i am putting it into bowl as shown in the video. And then putting it into the oven to bake on Normal temperature on which we are baking pizzas. And after sometime i am taking it out.

Comment: The video does not give much detail. Are you re-heating cooked pizza in the oven? What temperature are you baking them at and for how long?

Comment: No its just a Pizza bread. But what if i try to reheat it? It would be worst than this situation right?

Comment: Your post isn't clear what you are trying to do. The video shows someone cutting up a piece of pizza, yes you say you are using "pizza bread". You need to be much more detailed: what ingredients and what method are you using?

Comment: OK then let me put all the details in a short while.

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea; I will try it out.

In the video, they are only re-heating the left-over pizza pieces enough to have the additional cheese melt.

I would use the oven broil (put the dish on the lower rack) and **keep a constant eye on them** to not let them burn.